# Is there cleaner alternative of the original JAXA ALOS AW3D30 digital surface model (DSM) data?

Tags: geospatial, global

The team from JAXA made a great job on [DSM derived from ALOS-2](https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/index.htm). However, I find issues on data, e.g.:

- satellite stripes footprints, elevation drops by 1 to 5 metres
  [image: satellite paths footprints in JAXA ALOS DSM AW3D30 data, accessed 2020-06]
- rare, but obvious noise in data
  [image: rare noise in JAXA ALOS DSM AW3D30 data, accessed 2020-06]

Is there any version with cleaned/postprocessed global dataset, which deals with imperfections of AW3D30 data? (e.g. SRTM data were upgraded multiple times by various communities).